# Getting related models in sqlDataProvider in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Am performing query and i would like to get the related records in sqldataProvider in yii2

This is what i have tried

```
      $sql ="
        SELECT
    tblpritems.PRlineID
    , tblpritems.Tracking_Code
    , tblpritems.Description
    , tblpritems.Quantity
    , tblpritems.Unit_Price
    , tblpritems.Extended_price
    , tblpritems.PRID
    , tblpritems.pr_solicitation_id
    , tblpritems.date_item_received
    , tblpritems.Quantity_received
    , tblpritems.Remarks_on_receipt
    , tblpritems.Received_by

FROM
    prts.tblpritems
    INNER JOIN prts.tblpr 
        ON (tblpritems.PRID = tblpr.PRID)
    INNER JOIN prts.tblprsolicitations 
        ON (tblprsolicitations.PRID = tblpr.PRID) AND (tblpritems.pr_solicitation_id = tblprsolicitations.pr_solicitation_id)
    INNER JOIN prts.tblprsuppliers 
        ON (tblprsuppliers.pr_solicitation_id = tblprsolicitations.pr_solicitation_id)
    INNER JOIN prts.tblpo 
        ON (tblpo.pr_supplier_id = tblprsuppliers.pr_supplier_id)
  where tblpr.PRID=".$val." and tblpo.PO_Status_ID=7 and item_received_status=0
    ";

    $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $result = $command->queryAll();

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $sql,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);
```

When i perform

var_dump($dataProvider->getModels()); 
It returns all records but when i try

```
  $data = $dataProvider->getModels();
    foreach ($data as $dat) {
        $data = $dat->getRelatedRecords();
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

This always returns an error of Call to a member function getRelatedRecords() on array

How can i access the related record

Comment: What does `var_dump($data);` output? An array?

Comment: Yes returns an array

Comment: You will be unable to access model's relations as if it would be an instance of ActiiveRecord, because $data is not an instance of ActiveRecord. When you use SqlDataProvider, $dataProvider->getModels() returns list of arrays, not list of models.

Comment: Could you please advice on how i can change the sql to fit the active dataProvider way This is the link of a question i had asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095297/changing-sql-query-to-yii2-format

Comment: I have also added the database schema in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$data = $dataProvider->models;
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    var_dump($dat );
}
```

and in the $dat you cans easly see the you have  this pattern

```
model[i]->attri1;
model[i]->attr2;
 .....
model[i]->attrN;
```